# MVC View for Manipulating One-to-Many Relationships

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a one-to-many relationship WITHOUT lookups (i.e. the user can input their own data). I'm trying to determine the best UI for adding records. Here is what I have right now:

```
Table1
------
eventId
eventName

Table2
------
eventRepeatId
eventId
startTime
endTime
```

Table1 & Table2 are related through the eventId field. On my view, what I'm doing right now is tying the Table2 data to a multiselect box. The user clicks on a jQuery calendar, chooses a start and end time, and clicks an "add" button. This adds the new start/end time as an option to the multiselect box. Then, in my viewmodel method, I'm parsing the option and saving it to the DB.

This works currently. However, the caveat is that you have to have all of the options selected in the multiselect box when you hit "Create/Update". Otherwise, the data posted to the controller is null.

I'd like to find a method of adding and removing a number of start/end times to the event so that when I hit "Create/Update", they are all passed to the controller regardless of whether I have them selected or not.

Right now I'm leaning towards using jQuery to add/remove HTML elements (tables or divs) displaying the user's selections, and storing the data itself as JSON in a hidden form field. Just wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Check out the jQuery DataTable Editable project, https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

It allows you to transform an HTML table into an editable data grid that supports full CRUD (create read update delete).

Comment: @Ryios, thanks for the comment. I wasn't at the point to install a new library for one form, but it's good to know such a thing exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (I ended up using jQuery and a hidden field):

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
    <div id="dtpIS" class="row datetimepicker input-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="IrregularDPStart" data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm PP" />
            <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-date-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                </i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dtpIE" class="row datetimepicker input-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="IrregularDPEnd" data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm PP" />
            <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-date-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                </i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" id="IrregularAdd"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <table id="IDDTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" id="EventIrregularRepeats" name="EventIrregularRepeats" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var idd = [];
    function UpdateIdd() {
        idd = [];
        $("#IDDTable tbody tr").each(function () {
            var dates = [];
            var count = 0;
            $(this).child("td").each(function () {
                dates[count] = $(this).text();
                count++;
            })
            var newidd = { startTime: dates[0], endTime: dates[1] };
            idd.push(newidd);
        });

        $("#EventIrregularRepeats").val(JSON.stringify(idd));
    }
    $(function () {
        $("#IrregularAdd").on('click', function () {
            var tbody = $("#IDDTable tbody");
            var st = $("#IrregularDPStart").val();
            var end = $("#IrregularDPEnd").val();
            tbody.append("<tr><td>" + st + "</td><td>" + end + "</td><td><span class='iddremove glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></td>");
            UpdateIdd();
        })
        $('#IDDTable').on('click', '.iddremove', function () {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            UpdateIdd();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How data is posting to controller. R u using full postack when form post. Try to use ajax functionality to post form data.

try to add remove start and end time through java script. So when u post the form data then all selection will persist. Thanks

Comment: This would work for editing, but how can I add/remove new start/end times to a record that doesn't yet exist (i.e. new Events)? Should adding a new start/end time save the new Event first? I hate to make the end user create a record, then go back into it to choose start/end times.

Comment: Sorry im not being able to visualize you ui. Can u plz add any screen shot.i would suggest put ur start end date related ui in table row and put a button called add new. When user click on btn then clone the table row by jquery.

Comment: I ended up using jQuery with a hidden form field. User selects two dates and clicks "Add". This adds them to a table as well as to the hidden form field in JSON form. Controller Deserializes the JSON string back to the object.Thanks for the replies.